# Can jQuery perform an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

Can jQuery perform an "if" function? As in, if a class exists in one menu item, apply that class to a different menu item? This is slightly different than the usual active page menu highlighting, as I'm dealing with active dropdown menus and child pages.

What I'd like to do is

```
(the usual suspect) $(document).ready(function() {
```

If...

```
$('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1061') "contains the classes
current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent"

    then add those same classes to, i.e.:

    $('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1099').addClass('current-menu-ancestor
current-menu-parent')

}); });
```

Should be a way for this to work....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery is not a language, it is a library for JavaScript. The answer is: *"Yes, JavaScript has `if` statements as part of the language."*

I don't understand the pseudo-logic you have written. What do you mean by *"If [some list item] 'contains the classes' [foo] [bar]"*? If the list item has both of those classes? Either of those classes? Or if the list item has a descendant with at least one of those classes? Or if the list item has one or more descendants that have all of those classes?

Here is a solution using one interpretation:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var li = $('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1061');
  if ( li.find('.current-menu-ancestor, .current-menu-parent').length ){
    // do whatever you want here.
  }
});
```

Comment: It's "pseudo-logic" because that's the only way I know how to describe it. Looks like this will work, but I ended up finding a different way to accomplish what I needed with an if else php function to determine the body class of the page and then fire the add.Class.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a proper `if` statement on the existence of this?

```
$('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1061.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent')
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, `if` is a construct of JavaScript, not jQuery in particular. I think what you're looking for is the jQuery function [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), which can check DOM elements against the name of a class and will return true if the element currently has that class.

You can use it like this:

```
if (myElement.hasClass("myClass")) {
    // do something
}
```

Inside the `if` construct, you can insert the code you want to add the classes to the other elements.

**Updated:** Your example is a bit strange, in that you seem to wish to ask "does a set of elements matched against this selector have the classes `current-menu-ancestor` and `current-menu-parent`?" This is odd because you are matching a *set* of elements (your most specific selector is a class, so might return more than one item). It seems that you might have a design error in your HTML/CSS, since the class `menu-item-1061` sounds like it should be an ID (it's unique), not a class. Either way, the `hasClass` function will still work for you, since it returns `true` if *any* of the matched elements have the class.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look more into hasClass. The code is from a Wordpress generated menu and it deals with different kinds of active menu items and child pages.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can perform `if` statement, but in jQuery you can use `is` function 
to determine if any jquery object fit another expression.

for example, you have this jquery object

```
var firstObj = $(".selector1")
```

and you want to test if any of the element fit this expression

```
".selector2"
```

then you can use `is` as follows

```
firstObj.is(".selector2")
```

If any element fits then the response will be 'true', otherwise 'false'.
so you can combine with javascript's `if` as follows

```
if (firstObj.is(".selector2")){
    // you can do something here
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, seems like this would work. I ended up doing something different with php and add.Class.